# Thread-safe asynchronous Retrofit request

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit2

I'm struggling for few weeks now with this issue. I'm posting geolocation points to a server using **Retrofit 2.0**. I'm using a `IntentService` that I call every now and then when I have a new point to post.

For some reason, the server record the same point multiple time creating **LOTS** of duplicates. It seems that when I call my service and it's already active, it's will query the points and start a new request using some of the same points as was queried by the previous request. I also delete the point only when the request succeed. Is there a way to wait until executing the next batch of points?

How can I wait until all the processed point are sent to the server?

```
private String postAmazonPoints() throws IOException, JSONException {

    ArrayList<EntityPoint> points = new ArrayList<>(GenericDAO.getInstance(EntityPoint.class).queryForAll());

    if (points.size() == 0) {
        return RESULT_OK;
    }

    if (connectAmazonApi()) {
        int pointSize = points.size();
        if(pointSize>5){
            for(int i = 0; i<pointSize; i+=5){
                int end = i+5;
                if( end > pointSize ){
                    end = pointSize;
                }
                paginatePostPoint(points.subList(i, end-1));

            }
        }else{
            paginatePostPoint(points.subList(0, pointSize-1));
        }
    }

    return RESULT_OK;
}

private void paginatePostPoint(final List<EntityPoint> points) throws IOException, JSONException {

    EntityPoints mPoints = new EntityPoints(points);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = amazonServices.postGeopoints(mPoints);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                JSONObject json;
                try {
                    json = (response != null ? new JSONObject(response.body().string()) : null);
                    Log.e(TAG, json.toString());
                    if(RESULT_OK.equals(handleJsonRequest(json))){
                        deleteDatabasePoints(points);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Point are correctly posted");
                    }else{
                        addFirebaseMsg(json.toString());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

            } else {
                try {
                    addFirebaseMsg(response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            addFirebaseMsg(t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}

private void addFirebaseMsg(String message){
    isConnectedToAmz = false;
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, message.substring(0, Math.min(message.length(), 30)));
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(Constants.EVENT_TAG_ERROR, params);
    Log.d(TAG, message);
}


private boolean connectAmazonApi() {

    if (isConnectedToAmz) {
        return true;
    }

    Call<ResponseBody> call = amazonServices.postAuthenticate(settings.getString("token", ""),settings.getString(MyInstanceIDFireService.FIREBASE_TOKEN, ""), settings.getString("id", ""));

    String errMsg = "";
    try {
        ResponseBody response = call.execute().body();
        JSONObject json = (response != null ? new JSONObject(response.string()) : null);
        if (json != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + json.toString());
            RetrofitCreator.setAmazonToken(json.getString("token"));
            isConnectedToAmz = true;
            return true;
        }
        Log.w(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Amazon API : " + json);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        errMsg = e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errMsg = e.getMessage();
    }

    Log.w(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Amazon API");
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, 1);
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, errMsg.substring(0, Math.min(errMsg.length(), 30)));
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(Constants.EVENT_AMAZON_UNAVAILABLE, params);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.execute` instead of `.enqueue` and request will be synchronous, but in this case you should care about creating another thread for it. Create some service with asynсtask for example with queue.

Comment: I mean if you send using enqueue , you can't create some queue or something like that, but if you will use synchronous call, you can create something which can control your requests.